# PHP get value from post array

Tags: php, arrays

I'm posting an array from a html form with the following input-tag:

```
<input type="text" name="new_service[1]['category']">
```

I get this array:

```
Array
(
    [1] => Array
        (
            ['category'] => 1
            ['description'] => asdasd
            ['price'] => asdasd
            ['time'] => 1
        )

)
```

When I try to get the category value with

```
echo $_POST['new_service'][1]['category'];
```

I get this error message:

```
Notice: Undefined index: category
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The index you create this way is not category but 'category' i.e. you create an index that also has single quotes.

So to echo what you want you should use:

> echo $_POST['new_service'][1]["'category'"];

Answer (score 0):

Just use $_POST['new_service']; then loop